# how to configure websocket handle using class + spring 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

can any one help me please for how to configure this web socket bean and handler 
using class base rather than xml file.

```
<bean id="websocket" class="co.syntx.example.websocket.handler.WebsocketEndPoint"/>

<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/websocket" handler="websocket"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    <bean class="co.syntx.example.websocket.HandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in  your `WebSocketConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {  
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebsocketEndPoint(), "/websocket")
            .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

In the above code, `new WebsocketEndPoint()` that is `WebsocketEndPoint.java` will be your websocket handler and `new HandshakeInterceptor()` that is `HandshakeInterceptor.java` will be your interceptor.